# Dell XPS 15 9550 - Bluetooth will not connect to anything

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

Output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` on Linux Mint 19:

```
[    6.877551] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.877566] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.877568] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.877570] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.877573] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.969491] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.969492] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.969494] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.994787] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[    6.995787] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[    7.011813] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
[    7.012802] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[    7.012854] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[    7.012855] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[   45.103943] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   45.103948] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   45.103951] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  789.885847] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2364.579896] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2386.969769] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2795.783872] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2845.194748] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2894.203896] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2909.474876] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

I have no idea what patch the system is looking for here:

```
[    7.012854] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[    7.012855] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
```

Using either the standard Bluetooth app or blueman results in the same scenario: when scanning it "sees" Bluetooth items out there (but only shows MAC addresses which is annoying) but when I try to connect it hangs then fails. Any other tries after that and it fails immediately.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

To fix, do

```
wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM20703A1-0a5c-6410.hcd
sudo cp BCM20703A1-0a5c-6410.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
```

and reboot.

Comment: Worked great on my XPS 15 9550.